# What's the right way to update a meteor application distributed on the Apple Store?

Tags: ios, meteor

The problem, as you might expect, is the app review process.

In order to get Apple to review an app update, it has to be pointing at my production server. In order for that to work, I must update the build on my production server. But of course I don't want to do that until the app update is available in the Apple Store.

Now this isn't a problem if I've only made changes that can be deployed via hot code push ... but changes that can be deployed via hot code push don't need a new app wrapper anyway. I'm concerned about things like new node modules, or an updated meteor version.

Anybody know how meteor expects us to handle this?

(And in case it's useful, here's my related meteor forum post: https://forums.meteor.com/t/whats-the-right-way-to-do-updates-via-the-apple-store/28491)

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to introduce your own notion of versions of your app and during a transition have the server support both old and new.

Answer (score 0):

According to the meteor forums, the right way to do this is to package a separate release that just includes the wrapper-breaking changes (an update to the meteor version, for example).

Once that has been deployed (and "all users" have received it) then you can deploy updates that change the app interface.

... and since there's really no such thing as "all users" receiving the update, I'm thinking it might also be good to have the client know about breaking app wrapper versions and lock down somehow if the client's wrapper version is incompatible.

Comment: Note that this is already automatically handled by Meteor for core Cordova plugins. Whenever Meteor detects a new plugin or a version change on any of the core plugins, the bundle is stamped as not being deployable to clients who do not have a wrapper update. Those with the correct wrapper version can receive the bundle update. See: https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#updating-production-apps

Comment: A good point. So there's no hot code push to tank your app, but the client can still connect to the server ... which means things are fine until that second update drops, and all of a sudden one of your server methods has a different signature. I think for this app, at least, it would be preferable for the client to display a "your version is incompatible" message until the user gets the breaking update.